# Embedding Google Tag Manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

Should Google Tag Manager be added to every webpage, that can be lots of work if a site has a hundred pages?  What's the workaround?

Just added it to the home page. Am I missing anything if I only do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a share `head` block in all of you pages.

The best recommendation is add it on every page.

But you should look for a simple way to do it.

---

Like look for your website code structure. Is there anyway you can insert a code once and it can apply everywhere?

If none. Try to put the GTM code into one JS file. And let other file just include it.